# Construct a decidable set $B$ such that $B \neq A_w$ for any $w \in \Sigma^\star$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. Any hints would be appreciated!

Let $A \subseteq \Sigma^\star$ be decidable. Given $w \in \Sigma^\star$, define $$A_w = \{x \in \Sigma^\star\:|\: \langle x, w \rangle \in A\}.$$ 
Construct a decidable set $B$ such that $B \neq A_w$ for any $w \in \Sigma^\star$.

Comment: What is "$\langle x, w \rangle$"? is it the concatenation of $x$ and $w$?

Comment: It is the encoding of the tuple $(x, w)$. You can think of it as $x \# w$, where $\#$ is a symbol in $\Sigma$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for letting me know and for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hint. Let $w\in B$ if $w\not\in A_w$ and let $w\not\in B$ if $w\in A_w$.